# same function but but different id's and same varable in ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here i have 2 html rows. they have different ids.i want like when call the function  ItemSearch() to show both ids search result.actually i am new in javascript and ajax

```
   ***1st Html***
  <div class="justlauchSearch">
  <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width: 300px;">
    <input type="text" ****id="txtItemSearch"**** class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" />
         <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnItemSearchButton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>

***2nd html***
 <div class="justlauchSearch">
       <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width: 300px;">
           <input type="text" id="txtItemsSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"name="q"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnItemsSearchButton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
          </div>
           </div>
```

this my function start

```
function ItemSearch() {

        //if i comment this on the other id is working i want work both  of then in one function
            var SearchString = $("#txtItemSearch").val();  
            var SearchString = $("#txtItemsSearch").val();



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../PresentationLayer/POS/Pos.aspx/SearchItem",
                data: "{'SearchString':'" + SearchString + "'...etc......
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different variable names, and add them inside data:

```
var SearchString = $("#txtItemSearch").val();  
var SearchString2 = $("#txtItemsSearch").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../PresentationLayer/POS/Pos.aspx/SearchItem",
    data: { SearchString: SearchString, SearchString2: SearchString2 }
    ... 
})
```

Comment: it s not possible because this aja is usng different areas so....

Comment: is any other option to call this?

Comment: What is meant by ajax is using different areas?

Comment: here  i use only one stored procedure its have only one parameter but n your case  write one more parameter soit is not possible

Comment: You mean there are 2 different urls? `"../PresentationLayer/POS/Pos.aspx/SearchItem"` and another? Without giving complete information in the question how are you expecting anyone to resolve your issue?

Comment: @BrockJames if you want to run two searches you'll need to *combine the values* in 
 a way that your stored proc can handle - the best way to do this is to add 2nd parameter to your service (as detailed in this answer).  Your service then combines them when it makes the call to the stored proc using "OR" - but we can't advise on that as it depends on what your **service method does** (which you've not included).

Comment: @freedomn-m here i try to use jst 2 ajx call and i  got it thanks